# How to bind a Date from spring form to a dateTimePicker id?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, datetimepicker

I'm trying to bind a date field to a form, using dateTimePicker with no success.

In my .jsp I have a binding with `timeoutDate` which is a Date, so when trying to update the form i use (cleaned from some css stuff...)

```
<spring:bind path="timeoutDate">
    <div class="form-group>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-4" id='datetimepicker'>
            <form:input path="timeoutDate" id="timeoutDate" type="text"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
                {
                    defaultDate: "${timeoutDate}"
                });
        });
   </script>
   </div>
   </div >

</spring: bind >
```

`${timeoutdate}` does not work as `defaultDate`
if I don't put a default date in the function, no binding is made, the filed is empty...